# A forecast distribution implementation for Croston's model?

Tags: distributions, forecasting, crostons-method

I read the paper by [Shenstone and Hyndman](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/croston.pdf) on the distributional forecast underlying Croston's model. I looked into the forecast R package and the tsintermittent R package. Neither seem to have the distributional forecast implemented. Is there an alternative implementation or some code someone can point me to that implements this distributional forecast?